# Oracle can not startup after silent install completed

Tags: oracle, installation, silent

I install Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 on a Redhat 6.5 machine in silent mode,after configure all parameters,these error show up when I execute "startup".

I search on Google for answer,almost all the blog is about how to fix it after upgrade oracle to a newer version.But I have not upgrade my oracle,just install in silent mode.Anyone can help me????

```
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
ORA-00704: bootstrap process failure
ORA-39700: database must be opened with UPGRADE option
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, Bootstrap refers to loading some of metadata (data dictionary) before we OPEN the database.These objects are mandatory to bring up an instance and The it happens between MOUNT stage and OPEN stage. to troubleshoot problem you should trace it and find exact bootstrap object has problem. to do this use of sql_trace .change its value to true and then startup database. then find the trace file in diag path and check it to find exact problematic object.if it doesn't exist you should create it.
Regards